# Different design decisions with if-else-statements

Tags: java, if-statement, return

Which of the following would you prefer:

```
    SomeEnum enum = SomeEnum.SOMETHING;
    if (aString.equals(anotherString)) {
        enum = SomeEnum.SOMETHING_ELSE;
    }
    return foo.bar(enum);
```

or

```
    if (aString.equals(anotherString)) {
        return foo.bar(SomeEnum.SOMETHING_ELSE);
    }
    return foo.bar(SomeEnum.SOMETHING);
```

I think I would prefer the first one, because it only has 1 point of return. On the other side I think that the second one is easier to read. What do you think? Maybe you got an even more sophisticated solution.

Comment: I'd personally use the extra local variable, but with the conditional operator: `SomeEnum x = aString.equals(anotherString) ? SomeEnum.SOMETHING_ELSE : SomeEnum.SOMETHING; return foo.bar(x);` Not adding this as an answer as it's really an opinion question.

Comment: Do you plan on having several enums or is the code in question the only use case you have for this?

Comment: Several enums? I am just talking of one enum here and that is 'SomeEnum'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends on how many items we are talking about:

For a large enum, I would keep a map from String to enum Object. And I would look up the item in the map and provide SomeEnum.SOMETHING as default.

```
public SomeEnum get(String key, SomeEnum defaultValue){
    SomeEnum value = this.map.get(key);
    return value == null ? defaultValue : value;
}
```

For fewer items, I'd probably go with a switch statement:

```
public SomeEnum get(String key, SomeEnum defaultValue){
    switch(key){
        case "somevalue1" : return SomeEnum.SOME_VALUE_1;
        case "somevalue2" : return SomeEnum.SOME_VALUE_2;
        default: return defaultValue;
    }
}
```

But if it's actually just the two cases mentioned in the question, I'd go with

```
return aString.equals(anotherString) ? SomeEnum.SOMETHING_ELSE : SomeEnum.SOMETHING;
```

Comment: Given that you'll need some extra work to check whether the default is needed, it seems overkill to create a map for *one* value.

Comment: Subjective question but this is definitely the objectively best answer.

Comment: @christopher: I don't see how it's *objectively* best. What exact objective criteria are being used here?

Comment: @JonSkeet obviously I would only recommend this approach if there where more than two values involved

Comment: Well to me it scales quite well? I suppose it hinges on whether OP is going to have `if else if else if else` or just this one.

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd: Given that the question only involves those two values, and you don't mention this anywhere in the answer, I don't think there's anything obvious about that. How would you write code to answer the actual question being presented, rather than one where more values are involved?

Comment: @christopher: But it's introducing the complexity of having a map somewhere on the *supposition* that more comparisons will be used. It's easy to convert the single equality check into a map lookup *if and when* the code becomes more complex - but there's no obvious benefit to doing it initially, IMO.

Comment: I've asked OP anyway so we'll find out in a few minutes.

Comment: @JonSkeet I misread the question initially, I thought we were talking about multiple enum values.

Comment: OP has confirmed that the single enum solution is the correct one.

Comment: We are talking of two enum values. Do you really think the switch solution is a good one? I only know the imperative to not use switches if possible. Is the conditional operator something you should go for, rather than an if-else statement?

Comment: Note that the final option here doesn't call `foo.bar` with the enum value. I'd personally stick to two statements (but use a conditional operator to pick the enum value) but it *could* all be done in one...

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really matter. Simplifications like those will probably be optimized by the compiler! You should use whatever makes your code more readable!